# React props for passing color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props

I have many `div` elements with same size but with different colors. So I created a component 'Colors.jsx' in which I have the below code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Colors(props) {
  return (
    <div className="colors" style={{backgroundColor: {props.color}}}></div>
  );
}

export default Colors;
```

The problem is I'm getting these errors:

> /src/Colors.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (6:59)
> 4 | function Colors(props) {
> 5 | return (
> 6 | <div className="colors" style={{backgroundColor: {props.color}}}>
> ^ 7 | );
> 8 | }
> 9 |

> 4 | function Colors(props) {
> 5 | return (
> 6 | <div className="colors" style={{backgroundColor: {props.color}}}>
> ^ 7 | );
> 8 | }
> 9 |

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
> 4 | function Colors(props) {
> 5 | return (
> 6 | <div className="colors" style={{backgroundColor: {props.color}}}>
> ^ 7 | );
> 8 | }
> 9 | (null)

Comment: style={{backgroundColor: props.color}}

Comment: `{{backgroundColor: {props.color}}}`  ----> `{{backgroundColor: props.color}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<div className="colors" style={{backgroundColor: {props.color}}}></div>
```

You need to do like this(remove extra currly braces):

```
<div className="colors" style={{backgroundColor: props.color}}></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the brackets around `props.color` like this. Add the `children` to use your component clearly

```
function Colors(props) {
  return (
    <div className="colors" style={{backgroundColor: props.color}}>{props.children}</div>
  );
}
```

Then call it like that

```
<Colors color="#765739">Hello</Colors>
```